# Crawl spider not crawling ~ Rule Issue

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am having an issue with a spider that I am programming. I am trying to recursively scrape the courses off my university's website but I am having great trouble with `Rule` and `LinkExtractor`.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.spider import Spider
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

from ..items import BotItem

class UlsterSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ulster"
    allowed_domains = ["ulster.ac.uk"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://www.ulster.ac.uk/courses/course-finder?query=&f.Year_of_entry|E=2015/16&f.Type|D=Undergraduate',
    )

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=("index\.php", )), callback="parse"),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="pagination"]'), follow=True),
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = BotItem()

        for title in response.xpath('//html'):
            item['name'] = title.xpath('//*[@id="course_list"]/div/h2/a/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

My spider is laid out as follows. On lines 16 - 18 is the rules. What I have attempted to do is follow the pagination below the courses to scrape out the titles. However, it won't follow. It would be a great help if someone could point me in the right direction. I have tried to duplicate examples using SGML extractor but it says it has been deprecated and not to use it.

**Disclaimer**

Although this is a university website, this is NOT homework. It is for fun and learning. I am just really really stuck.

Comment: Homework questions are perfectly acceptable on SO, we even have a [tag:homework] tag, provided they follow the guidelines set [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). IMO being able to properly ask a question on SO is a pretty valuable skill as you will likely be back here after you graduate so there is nothing wrong with getting a little help (your professor may feel differently of course).

Comment: What are you trying to capture with your first rule?  It doesn't seem to catch anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you need two rules, you can declare one and do it to follow links and parse each page.

In the rule I restrict the `xpath` to the last link of the list, because otherwise you could be parsing some links multiple times.

I use `parse_start_url` as callback to include the url of `start_urls` variable.

In the `xpath` command, it returns a list with all the text between tags, but the interesting one is the first, so get it and strip blanks.

With following `items.py`:

```
import scrapy

class BotItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
```

And the spider:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from ..items import BotItem
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class UlsterSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "ulster"
    allowed_domains = ["ulster.ac.uk"]
    start_urls = ( 
        'http://www.ulster.ac.uk/courses/course-finder?query=&f.Year_of_entry|E=2015/16&f.Type|D=Undergraduate',
    )   

    rules = ( 
        Rule(
            LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[@class="pagination"]/ul/li[position() = last()]'), 
            follow=True, 
            callback='parse_start_url'),
    )   

    def parse_start_url(self, response):
        item = BotItem()

        for title in response.xpath('//*[@id="course_list"]/div/h2/a'):
            item['name'] = title.xpath('text()')[0].extract().strip()
            yield item
```

You can run it like:

```
scrapy crawl ulster -o titles.json
```

That yields:

```
[{"name": "ACCA - Association of Chartered Certified Accountants"},
{"name": "Accounting"},
{"name": "Accounting"},
{"name": "Accounting and Advertising"},
{"name": "Accounting and Human Resource Management"},
{"name": "Accounting and Law"},
{"name": "Accounting and Management"},
{"name": "Accounting and Managerial Finance"},
{"name": "Accounting and Marketing"},
{"name": "Accounting with Finance"},
{"name": "Advertising"},
{"name": "Advertising and Human Resource Management"},
{"name": "Advertising with Computing"},
{"name": "Advertising with Drama"},
{"name": "Advertising with Human Resource Management"},
{"name": "Advertising with Psychology"},
...]
```

---

**UPDATE**: Note that I'm using last `scrapy` version. I don't know if it matches with yours, so maybe you need to adapt some imports.

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you mind breaking down your XPath link a bit more? ~ `//div[@class="pagination"]/ul/li[position() = last()]` I'm not entirely understanding `[position() = last()]`.

Comment: @plotplot: It means `li[-1]`, but the `xpath` way.

Answer (score 3):

Some things you should consider:

1. **Debugging:**
   Scrapy has several ways to help determine why your spider is not behaving the way you want/expect.  Check out [Debugging Spiders](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/debug.html#debugging-spiders) in the scrapy docs; this may well be the most important page in the docs.
2. **You are confusing your Spider:**
   Again referring to the [scrapy docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/master/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules), you will find the following

> **Warning**
>
> When writing crawl spider rules, avoid using `parse` as callback, since
>   the `CrawlSpider` uses the `parse` method itself to implement its logic.
>   So if you override the `parse` method, the crawl spider will no longer
>   work.

Use a different name for a non-default callback.

3. **Check your spider's behavior:**
   You'll probably want to revise your item-loading code; I suspect the list you are getting is not what you want.